# Is a creature that is not on the ground affected by the Sleet Storm spell's risk of falling prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, area-of-effect, flight

The spell [*sleet storm*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sleet-storm) on page 276 in the *Player's Handbook* says, in part:

> The ground in the area is covered with slick ice, making it difficult terrain. When a creature enters the spell's area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, it must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, it falls prone.

The fact that the ground in the area is covered with slick ice seems to be connected to the reason a creature might fall prone. On the other hand, the spell doesn't explicitly state that the affected creature has to be on the ground.

Are creatures that are not on the ground (e.g. flying or swimming) but are in the area of the spell still affected?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Freezing rain and sleet interfere with flying.

The effect of the slick ground is given explicitly:

> The ground in the area is covered with slick ice, making it difficult terrain.

However, the spell's area includes more than just icy ground:

> freezing rain and sleet fall in a 20-foot-tall cylinder with a 40-foot radius centered on a point you choose within range.

When it comes to falling prone, the only triggering condition is:

> When a creature enters the spell's area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there

It does not require that you be touching the ground, only that you enter the spell's area, which is:

> a 20-foot-tall cylinder with a 40-foot radius centered on a point you choose within range.

So we conclude that a creature only needs to be in the area to trigger the dexterity save against falling prone, whether they be walking or flying. Narratively, this looks like freezing rain and sleet pelting the flying creature as it tries to stay aloft in the torrent.

Comment: Apparently even a white dragon flying through the spell's area has to make the save by RAW, though I'd likely rule that it is immune if it ever actually came up.

Comment: So, by the spell's 'area', it means its volume?

Comment: @Kirt That is correct.

Comment: @Kirt Yes, 5e consistently uses "area" to mean the entire region affected by a spell, regardless of whether that region is 2D or 3D. The section describing the different 3D shapes is even titled ["Areas of Effect"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AreasofEffect).

Comment: Can you improve on what it narratively looks like by adding something for a swimming/diving creature?

Comment: @LitPit I'd say turbulent currents and sudden temperature drops.

Comment: Just as a note: freezing rain is absolutely *awful* stuff to try to fly in because of the way it can (and will) ice up one's wings, ruining their ability to generate lift.  (Look up "supercooled large droplet icing" if you want the details.)